# How to change resharper 'usages window' selection hightlight color?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

I am using Resharper with visual studio 2010 for C# development. By 'Usages Window' I mean the tabbed window where usages are shown when there is more than one usage of the symbol searched for. The problem I have is that the selected line background is dark gray while the font color is black and it is very hard to read that line. I looked through 'fonts and colors' in VS and couldn't find/guess any 'Resharper xxx' setting to change this color. Is there any way to change this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the following color `Control Panel | Personalization | Window Color | "Item" dropdown | "Selected Item"`

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it doesn't invert the font color, and also decides the background color light/darkness based on the system setting. But it works for me.